# Can XGBoost handle dependency between outcomes?

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, modeling, boosting, cart

Assume I have the following dataset:

| Race Id | Athlete Id | Athlete weight | Athlete height | Winner |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 50 | 180 | 0 |
| 1. | 2 | 48 | 177 | 1 |
| 1. | 3 | 52 | 182 | 0 |
| 2. | 2 | 48 | 178 | 1 |
| 2. | 1 | 48 | 178 | 0 |
| 2. | 5 | 50 | 165 | 0 |
| 2. | 7 | 52 | 188 | 0 |

We consider two races; the first race being ran by 3 athletes, while second by 4 athletes. Then, there is a winner flag associated with the runner that won the race.

Assuming that the outcomes are the winner of the races, and we use a multiclass classifier that gives back the probabilities, is there a way to specify a variable number of classes using eXtreme Gradient Boosting (XGB)? If yes, how do I specify the number of classes based on each race, and how do you get the dependencies between observations (Note, the probability for each class in a particular race should sum up to 1).

In this scenario we model the race outcome (i.e., which athlete will win) rather than the outcome for each independent athlete, hence the athletes can be considered dependent rather than independent.

As pointed in the comments, the explanation above might be vague, so I can summarise with the following two questions:

How can you model different choices per event (in this case of a race) using a boosting algorithm ? For example one event (a race in this scenario) can have athletes A, B, C while another race can have athletes B, C Z, P. Each athlete has a set of features.

How can you model the dependence between choices (in this case athletes) competing in the same race ? In multinomial logit models, the dependency is respected and the outcome is a subset of probabilities for each athlete to win the race, probabilities which sum up to 1.

I am not interested in renormalizing the probabilities of each athlete so their sum is 1, I want to consider the collection of athletes competing against each other as an input to the boosting model.

Comment: You are asking two different questions, could you split them into two? Also, the first question is hard to answer without more details. What are the classes for your classifier? I guess it's an athlete I'd, so you have the same number each time. Otherwise, I can't make sense of what could the classes be.

Comment: I agree there are two questions. The classes are the athleteIds which are not necessarily the same between the two races.  In one race you can have athlete a, b, c while in another you can have b, c, z and p.

Comment: The second question is how do you make sure that the dependency between athletes in a race is respected. (Eg. Get a set of probabilies for each athlete that specifies the probability of win when he is competing against that subset of opponents). In a multinomial logit scenario, these probabilities would sum up to 1. How do you model this using xgb ? Or any other boosting library.

Comment: @Tim I have updated it my initial question. Hopefully this brings some clarification.

Comment: The problem does not have any sense if your classes change from case to case. If you had a cat vs dog classifier and in half of the cases cats were coded as 1 and in the other half as 0, when your classifier sees an image of a cat, should it return 1 or 0?

Comment: You're considering the problem abstracted from the real world, it is a valid case, despite refusing to acknowledge it. Learn to rank takes in consideration about this case and XGB has a Ranker that can sort your predictions based on a score, despite the options to rank changing from one event to another.

Comment: This is a very common usecase in marketing (not that I'm modeling anything marketing related, however the choice alternative does not have to be symmetric.) Your example is also unreasonable. If I have 10 google queries, do I need to consider the entire universe of possible links as answers OR each query will represent a particular subset (with possible intersections) of different choices. In your case, for each query you'd consider all the possible urls as solution. I think this is a more reasonable counter example to your comment.

Comment: Without ending up in a very long debate about this, do you know this being possible with XGB or not without trying to reformulate my entire problem ?

Comment: Learning to rank is a different problem. For a classification problem, each class *needs* to have the same meaning for all the rows of your data. Either you didn't give us all details about the problem or this formulation is simply wrong. There is a number of ways how this could be solved, but not via multiclass classification with classes that mean different things for different rows.

Comment: I don't have more information, that's literally about it. Multiple races, with different athletes competing. Just to clarify on your last comment, each row is a "choice" in a particular race, as in the table above.

Comment: Then it is not a multiclass classification problem.

Comment: How would you classify this problem with the knowledge to hand ? Is it perhaps a limitation of the classifier ? Multinomial logit with variable number of classes are perfectly correctly specified in a regression setup and there are libraries available to handle the scenario.

Comment: You can frame it as a binary classification task, or ranking task, but not multi-class classification. You technically could make it a multi-class classification if your labels were “1 place”, “2 place”,  ..., “nth place”, but regression would be a better idea for such data.

Comment: Thank you. I do have a regression model however I was looking at boosting algorithms knowingly that they perform better (or at least I'm biased to believe so) than regression models, and I was curious on how you'd fit such a model.